# Missing values between GET and POST method

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

I'm learning Spring Boot and I have a problem. I'm creating an Order in one form and then adding the user's details in the second. The second form's `GET` method has the parameter NewOrder and it's received well (checked using a debugger). Then in this form I'm creating OrderDetails, in which is saved NewOrder and some Strings. Then I'm passing it to the repository using `POST` method, but in created OrderDetails, there're only Strings and NewOrder is `null`. How could I resolve it?

First POST method (from the first controller):

```
@PostMapping
    public String processOrder( @ModelAttribute NewOrder order, final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("order", order);
    ordersProxy.addOrder(order);
    return "redirect:/sendOrder";
      }
```

Second controller (POST and GET):

```
 @GetMapping
      public String showSendOrderForm(Model model, @ModelAttribute("order") NewOrder order) {
         model.addAttribute("details", new OrderDetails(order) );
         model.addAttribute("companies", companyProxy.getCompanies());
        return "orderDetails";
      }
    
    @PostMapping
    public String processTaco( OrderDetails details) {
       detailsProxy.addOrderDetails(details);
        return "orderDetails";
      }
```

And here, the OrderDetails details in Post Order is null.

orderDetails.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
  <head>
    <title>Taco Cloud</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/styles.css}" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="POST" th:object="${details}">
     <a th:href="@{/design}" id="another">Order</a><br/>
      <h3>Deliver to...</h3>
      <label for="name">Name: </label>
      <input type="text" th:field="*{name}"/>
      <br/>
      <label for="surname">Surname: </label>
      <input type="text" th:field="*{surname}"/>
      <br/>
      <label for="room">Room: </label>
      <input type="text" th:field="*{room}"/>
      <br/>
       <br/>
      <h2>Please, choose your company:</h2>
       <select th:field="*{company}">
    <option th:each="i : ${companies}" th:value="${i.id}" th:text="${i.name}">
    </option>
</select>
         </div>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit Order"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

OderDetails class:

```
@Data
@Entity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor(access=AccessLevel.PRIVATE, force=true)
public class OrderDetails {
    @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
     private Integer id; 
    private  String name;
      private  String surname;
      private  String room;
@OneToOne
      private final NewOrder order;
@ManyToOne
private  Company company;
}
```

I have also tried to pass NewOrder directly to POSTmethod and there add order to details, but it was still null.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `@RequestBody` should work for null OrderDetails. Check out this for more about it: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-response-body

```
@PostMapping
public String processTaco(@RequestBody OrderDetails details) {
   detailsProxy.addOrderDetails(details);
   return "orderDetails";
}
```